# Issue with isset() inside nested ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am trying to show a input field value using `if-else` login and I want to use single line `ternary` operator for it but its always returning the error. However if I use `if-else` it is working fine. My code is :

**Working Fine**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['m_name'])){
    echo $_COOKIE['m_name']; 
}else if(isset($this->userdata)){
    echo $this->userdata[0]->first_name;
}else{
    echo 'No Data';
}
```

**Returning Notice Always**

```
echo isset($_COOKIE['m_name'])? $_COOKIE['m_name']: isset($this->userdata)?$this->userdata[0]->first_name:'No Value';
```

**Error :**

> > Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/.... on line...

I don't know what i am missing?

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: I would prefer the way without multiple combined ternary operators as it's better readable.

Comment: Thank You @Alex2php! But I have to sort out this.

Comment: Thank You @Alex2php ! issue resolved. Now I will follow your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think it should be

```
echo (isset($_COOKIE['m_name'])? $_COOKIE['m_name']: (isset($this->userdata)?$this->userdata[0]->first_name:'No Value'));
```

Comment: Thank You @Dmnik ! :) Its working fine.. And you teach me the basics that i was missing. Keep it up. Best Start on SO.  Happy Coding :)